# When would multiple `///` be used between sub-directories?

Tags: command-line, syntax, directory-structure

I was digging through `/var/log/plymouth-debug.log` and spotted this line:

```
[main.c:716] get_cache_file_for_mode:returning cache file '/var/lib/plymouth//boot-duration'
```

I thought it was a typo so typed the following and sure enough you can have as many `///` between sub-directories and file name as you want. For example:

```
rick@dell:~$ ls -la /var/lib/plymouth/boot-duration
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2041 Nov  3 21:39 /var/lib/plymouth/boot-duration
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
rick@dell:~$ ls -la /var/lib/plymouth/////boot-duration
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2041 Nov  3 21:39 /var/lib/plymouth/////boot-duration
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
rick@dell:~$ ls -la /var/lib//plymouth///boot-duration
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2041 Nov  3 21:39 /var/lib//plymouth///boot-duration
```

Under what circumstances would you want to use two or more `//` instead of a single `/` separator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is answered very nicely by [Gilles](https://askubuntu.com/users/1059/gilles) over at Unix & Linux: 
[How does Linux handle multiple consecutive path separators (/home////username///file)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/1910/70524)

> Multiple slashes are allowed and are equivalent to a single slash.
>   From the [Single Unix specification (version
>   3)](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/), [base definitions
>   §3.266
>   pathname](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap03.html#tag_03_266):
>   “Multiple successive slashes are considered to be the same as one
>   slash.”
>
> There is one exception: if a pathname starts with exactly two slashes,
>   it may be treated differently (ref: [base definitions §4.11 pathname
>   resolution](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap04.html#tag_04_11)).
>   Linux itself doesn't do this, though some applications might, and
>   other unix-ish system do (e.g. Cygwin).
>
> A trailing `/` at the end of a pathname forces the pathname to refer
>   to a directory. In ([POSIX 1003.1-2001 (Single Unix v3) base
>   definitions §4.11 pathname
>   resolution](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap04.html#tag_04_11),
>   a trailing `/` is equivalent to a trailing `/.`. [POSIX 1003.1-2008
>   (Single Unix v4) base definitions
>   §4.12](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap04.html#tag_04_12)
>   removes the requirement to make it equivalent to `/.`, in order to
>   cope with non-existing directories (e.g. `mkdir foo/` is required to
>   work, whereas `mkdir foo/.` wouldn't — see the
>   [rationale](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xbd_chap04.html#tag_21_04_12)
>   for the change).
>
> For programs that act on a directory entry, if `foo` is a symbolic
>   link to a directory, then passing `foo/` is a way to make the program
>   act on the directory instead of the symbolic link.
>
> ¹  <sub>Note that this applies for pathname resolution only, i.e. when
>   accessing files. Filename manipulations may work differently. For
>   example
>   [`basename`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/basename.html)
>   and
>   [`dirname`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/dirname.html)
>   ignore trailing slashes.</sub>

In this case, I'm assuming `///` is just programming over-cautiousness (some dev using `/` to join paths when they already have trailing or leading slashes respectively).

Comment: The link confirms `/TopDir///MiddleDir/////BottomDir///FileName` is valid syntax but doesn't say when, where and why it is used. The link does provide helpful insights on `//` prefix and `/` sufix.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix O.o use multiple slashes whenever and however you want to use single slashes, except at the start. You did read the last line, didn't you?

Comment: Yes I agree with your observation it is helpful building path-names and not worrying about adding two strings together like "/directory-a/" + "/directory-b/" + "/directory-c/" in different sub-routines without having to worry about current strings already ending in `/` or not.